# .NET MVC3 : Create Virtual file URL and redirect to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Suppose I got a MVC3 website with a URL like this:
http://www.anything.com/**feed.xml**

The trick is, the file **feed.xml** does not really exist, it will be generated dynamically by a controller at runtime. That way, it will be transparent to people. Any idea how should I bind the controller to the virtual URL?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you change the url?  It would probably be better if the url were just /feed rather than feed.xml, then you don't have to setup any custom routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
routes.MapRoute("", "feed.xml", new { controller = "Feed", action = "Index" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom route and return `File result` from action. Look at this links:

- [Back to Basics: Dynamic Image Generation, ASP.NET Controllers,
  Routing, IHttpHandlers, and runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx)
  (in your situation no need for custom `RouteHandler`)
- [ASP.NET MVC Uploading and Downloading Files](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files) (how return file)